# Verb for two uncountable items

Tags: verb-forms, uncountable-nouns

What verb form should I use when talking about two uncountable items?

Which of these sentences is correct?

> 1.There **are** lightning and thunder.
>
> 2.There **is** lightning and thunder.

Answer (score 7):

***Lightning*** and ***thunder*** are both uncountable nouns, but there are ***two*** of them, i.e. it is possible to count uncountable-noun words. For this reason we use the plural form ***are***:

> Lightning and thunder **are** both natural phenomena.

The confusion arises because we also have an idiomatic phrase in English ***thunder and lightning***, which is treated as a (singular) noun phrase:

> There ***is*** thunder and lightning in the sky.
>
> The thunder and lightning ***is*** pretty scary, huh?

Technically you could break the noun-phrase from the singular "thunder and lightning" back into its constitutent parts of "thunder" and "lightning" and so something like this is technically grammatical:

> (X) The thunder and lightning are pretty scary.

It ***is*** grammatical (replace the nouns to see this fact: "*the rain and hail are pretty scary!*" is perfectly grammatical), but it is extremely unidiomatic, and no native English speaker would say it.

Answer (score -1):

There is lightning and thunder.

This is the correct usage of the verb form. However I'm unclear of the reason why (maybe someone could elaborate.